# Overflow Hidden is not working for me in Html Div

Tags: html, css

I am using the following html, See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H3nXk/)

```
        <div style="float: left;">
            <div style="padding-left: 3px; padding-top: 3px;">
                <div style="float: left;">
                    Title: 
                </div>
                <div style="float: left; padding-left: 12px">
                    ABC
                </div>
                <div style="clear: both"></div>
            </div>
            <div style="padding-left: 3px; padding-top: 3px;">
                <div style="float: left;">
                    Lyrics: 
                </div>
                <div style="float: left; padding-left: 3px">
                    <div style="overflow: hidden; width: 180px">
                        ABC DEF GHI JKl MNO dsa  dsa sddsa d s
                    </div>
                    <div style="overflow: hidden; width: 180px">
                        ABC DEF GHI JKl MNO MNO dsa  dsa sddsa d s
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="clear: both"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div style="float: right; border-left: 1px solid black;">

            <img src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/snowish/72x72/actions/gtk-media-play-ltr.png">
        </div>
    </div>
```

But my text overflow is not hidden.
When I use small text instead of '

> ABC DEF GHI JKl MNO dsa  dsa sddsa d s

' then everything is fine.

Comment: `overflow` is not doing what you are expecting it to do. Look for `word-wrap`, `white- space` etc.

Comment: Is this http://jsfiddle.net/H3nXk/2/ what you want to do? I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Give `white-space: nowrap`:

```
    <div style="float: left;">
        <div style="padding-left: 3px; padding-top: 3px;">
            <div style="float: left;">
                Title: 
            </div>
            <div style="float: left; padding-left: 12px">
                ABC
            </div>
            <div style="clear: both"></div>
        </div>
        <div style="padding-left: 3px; padding-top: 3px;">
            <div style="float: left;">
                Lyrics: 
            </div>
            <div style="float: left; padding-left: 3px">
                <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; width: 180px; ">
                    ABC DEF GHI JKl MNO dsa  dsa sddsa d s
                </div>
                <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; width: 180px">
                    ABC DEF GHI JKl MNO MNO dsa  dsa sddsa d s
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="clear: both"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="float: right; border-left: 1px solid black;">

        <img src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/snowish/72x72/actions/gtk-media-play-ltr.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H3nXk/1/

---

#### Or if you are concerned about height, you need to specify `height` explicitly.

Comment: Is you know that how to make this responsive?

Comment: Yeah, we can make it responsive. What you wanna do @user960567?

Comment: Responsive means Responsive web design.

Comment: Dude, according to the screen availability, rearranging... Yeah, I know.. WHat do YOU wanna do?

Comment: The current no look good equally in mobile, tablet and desktop.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a height in order for the container to know where the overflow starts.